# How to convert emojis from to unicode in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin.Forms project. I have textbox in that and have a button which get text from textbox and pass it to API to store. Now the point is when user select any emojis from keyboard, I want to get unicode character of the emojis. Currently I am getting emojis it self when I check `Text` property of it.
[image]

I want to get Unicode rather emoji as given in `NewTextValue` from `Text` property.

This post is same but I don't understand how the guy has managed. [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728740/how-to-convert-emoticons-to-its-utf-32-escaped-unicode)

Please suggest.

After some google, I have tried with following.

```
string res = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(str)).Replace("-", "");
```

This is result `res = D83DDE00`
I don't know above code is unicode or not.

How can I convert back to original emoji or is there any other way to convert in unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to manually convert it back. Insert "-" every two characters:

```
var convertStr = string.Join("-", Regex.Matches(res, @"..").Cast<Match>().ToList());
String[] tempArr = convertStr.Split('-');
byte[] decBytes = new byte[tempArr.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < tempArr.Length; i++)
{
    decBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(tempArr[i], 16);
}
String str = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(decBytes);
```

Moreover in my test, `Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes()` may be closer to emoji code. You can test it with `\U0001F600`, this is a smile image. After converting with utf32, the bytes just change its order.

Comment: Your solution is useful. But everytime checking this is not a appropriate way. What I did is, convert whole string in Base64 and visa versa in storing and retrieving.